# Change Orientation on Jquery Parallax Effect

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I´m using a simple Scrolldeck Jquery Parallax effect to scroll itens at different speeds but i´m having some trouble to make itens move from top to bottom, on the example below you can find a shoe moving from bottom to top at different scroll speed.

I´ve tried to change css position to negative values, change outerHight values but i can´t find a EndPoint to the transition, only the startPoint, maybe that´s why i can´t achieve this.

I want to make the same thing but moving the same shoe from top to bottom, as the page is scrolled, as i see on many sites, anyone can help me with that ?

Example:
http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax/

Answer (score 0):

the parallax scrolling is best explained at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Easy, fast and good way to implement the technique.

Comment: I have seen a lot of Parallax tutorials, but i don´t see why code everything again instead of using a plugin that already exist. The link that you provided only show simple movements, don´t show what i´m looking for. Anyway, thanks for the help.